# How to configure proxy settings visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am creating a android xamarin project on visual studio but when ever i build my project i get an error proxy authentication required error 407 and also it fails to download m2repository i think its because of this proxy thing. even my eclipse is not working because of proxy when i try to change my proxy in eclipse it does not allow me my proxy address is set to native automatically i can remove it or edit no option do do any of those things. I have tried downloading the m2 repository and manually add it but i guess the problem is the proxy

Comment: I just uses system proxy as far as I know

Comment: Are you trying to download and open a xamarin android project using eclipse?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 but when i build my android xamarin project i get error 407 and error failed to download m2repository

Comment: I am facing the error 407 even eclipse when i open marketplace